# \framebox and tabbing not working together

Tags: framed, tabbing

I wanted to frame in a box a text which includes `tabbing`. Both `\framebox` and `tabbing` works fine separately but cannot make them work together.

```
\framebox{
\begin{tabbing} 
\textit{Input:} \hspace*{13mm} \= assd \\
\textit{Problem:} \> adas  \\
\end{tabbing}
}
```

Comment: Not sure whether this is an alternative to your usage, but using you can use some `\phantom`s achieve the appropriate alignment.

Answer (score 3):

You can box the `tabbing` before framing it; in the following example I show two possibilities; the firs one, using a `\vbox` and the second one using a `varwidth` environment from the [`varwidth`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\framebox{%
\vbox{\begin{tabbing} 
\textit{Input:} \hspace*{13mm} \= assd \\
\textit{Problem:} \> adas
\end{tabbing}}%
}

\framebox{\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\begin{tabbing} 
\textit{Input:} \hspace*{13mm} \= assd \\
\textit{Problem:} \> adas
\end{tabbing}
\end{varwidth}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You seem to be typesetting algorithms; in this case, some dedicated packages such as [`algorithmicx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) or [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) could be useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\itshape}l@{}l|}
  \hline
  Input: \hspace*{13mm} & assd \\
  Problem:              & adas \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A `\framebox` expects only material that doesn't split across lines; so we need to box the `tabbing`; if a `minipage` contains only a `tabbing` environment, it will adapt its width to that of the `tabbing` (if smaller than the stated width).

You are probably better served from a new environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newsavebox{\ftabbingbox}
\newenvironment{ftabbing}
  {\begin{lrbox}{\ftabbingbox}
   \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
   \begin{tabbing}}
  {\end{tabbing}
   \end{minipage}
   \end{lrbox}
   \fbox{\usebox{\ftabbingbox}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{ftabbing}
\textit{Input:} \hspace*{13mm} \= assd \\
\textit{Problem:} \> adas
\end{ftabbing}

\end{document}
```

[image]